# Apart from immutability, does blockchain offer any other advantages?

Tags: database-design, data-structures, data, cryptography

I am trying to understand the broader implications of blockchain apart from the main advantage of immutability. Are there any?

It seems like the distributed nature of the ledger can be an asset when it comes to data redundancy but it also seems like performance would be terrible since, as I understand it, all the history of an entity is encoded into each record in the chain that then presumably has to propagate throughout the node network.

How would one even query a blockchain to determine, for example, the location of a piece of inventory? It seems like the advantages outside of immutability of data are almost non-existent, but I feel I must be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with the distributed nature of the ledger.  You are also correct that performance is a challenge.

The key value, from a business perspective, is that there is no need for a central authority.  Distributing your data is a good thing for many reasons such as fault-tolerance and latency but there are many ways of doing that.  What makes block chain different is that there no concept of a leader and no authority.  Each participant in the system is a peer and is the authority in their own transactions.  If you and I want to make a deal, we do our deal and then propagate what happened to the other participants.  There's a lot of complexity in how conflicts get managed, of course, but that's the happy path goodness of it.

This makes a lot of sense when you are talking about market or other system with many independent actors.  In a more traditional system, you need someone or something to oversee all the transactions.  This creates a bottleneck and essentially a company or governmental organization needs to exist just to do this.  This authority also can't easily be replaced so what they should get paid becomes an issue.  With blockchain system such as bitcoin, anyone can be involved in transaction verification.  In fact it [depends on many people being involved in mining and/or verification](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/51-attack.asp).

Inventory management doesn't seem like an obvious choice here.  Most companies don't want other people to know those kinds of details.  And if you are talking about an single company system, there are much easier ways to solve the problem.

On system that I think blockchain might be useful for is DNS.  Right now, we have companies like [Dyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Dyn_cyberattack) that much of the internet depends on for domain name resolution.  When something bad happens to these providers, huge swaths of the internet break.  If instead you had a massive network of DNS servers using a blockchain ledger, you change that dynamic greatly (although there may be other, different kinds of issues.)  It also would be much harder to [take over a domain without anyone noticing](https://www.wired.com/2017/04/hackers-hijacked-banks-entire-online-operation/).

Comment: This is a really great answer, thank you. You definitely made it more clear for me, but I am still struggling a little. Am I correct in surmising that if I were to buy a used car that had been three previous owners, then every transaction (sale of the car, oil change, DMV registration, etc) would be baked into every single record in this system? In other words, does each record hold an entire database of knowledge (at least for that entity)? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not really an expert in this but yes I believe this is a core feature of blockchain technology.  This can be a point of confusion since people think of bitcoin as anonymous but it's actually kind of tricky to make transactions untraceable with bitcoin.

Comment: Thanks @JimmyJames. I am working on a blog post for this and would like to possibly include your example about DNS. Is that alright? If so, how do I properly attribute you as being the source (assuming you would like the attribution)? Thanks!

Comment: @JimmyJames: IIRC, there was a question on [security.se] or [cryptography.se] just recently which asked exactly that (and got some good answers). The key is: mixing (which is essentially what money laundering is in real currency).

Comment: @MattCashatt I wouldn't mind you using it but I must warn you that it's nothing more than a half-baked idea that I had.  I'm not aware of anyone who really knows the relevant details suggesting this.  For one, there would need to be some sort of centralized control of the issuance of domain names.  They aren't fungible like bitcoins.  I think the most interesting stuff happening in this space is with Ethereum which contains a Turing-complete language something something.  You might want to read up on the smart contract stuff.  If you do mention it, a not of attribution would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @JimmyJames, I will definitely credit you and also post a link herein when it's all done. Thanks again.